# how much better is thread-context switch from process context-switch?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I was just wondering how much efficient is thread context switch as compared to process context-switch. Both involve switching of register values. Is Flushing of TLB in process switch the only thing that creates the difference ?

Comment: What OS are you referring to?

Comment: Does the OS matter? I have read that thread switch is always faster than a process context switch.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, they are very close to the same thing. See [Threads vs Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807506/threads-vs-processes-in-linux) in Linux. In Windows, processes are a lot heavier than threads.