# Sites to research processes and Threads in the Linux 2.6 Kernel

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel, process

Hey I have been given an essay to write about Processes and threads in the 2.6 Linux Kernel but we are unable to talk about the general concepts of processes and thread management. I am kind of stuck for material as I have only wrote about the history of Linux, what the kernel is and what it does, can anyone direct me to good sites or topics I should look into I am having a hard time finding something worthwhile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope these initial pointers help

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-scheduler/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=370047

[Threads vs Processes in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807506/threads-vs-processes-in-linux)

Comment: Thank you these articles are a great help