# Difference between Schdeuling of Process and Threads.

Tags: operating-system

What are the differences between scheduling of process and threads and difference between methods of IPC's between thread and process. Do all IPC's mechanism like semaphores, mutex, spinlock etc can be applied for the scheduling of  process and threads.???

Comment: Which operational system? May be this thread can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807506/threads-vs-processes-in-linux

Comment: Ipc = Inter Process Communication. With threads, the programmer has to take care of synchronization amongst them, not the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The process is the circle, representing the "container" concept (the address space), and the three squigley lines are the threads.

We are scheduling threads

A process is a program in execution, whereas a thread is a path of execution within a process.