# How does Apache spark handle python multithread issues?

Tags: python, multithreading, apache-spark

According to [python's GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19614263) we cannot use threading in CPU bound processes so my question is how does Apache Spark utilize python in multi-core environment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multi-threading python issues are separated from Apache Spark internals. Parallelism on Spark is dealt with inside the JVM.

[image]

And the reason is that in the Python driver program, `SparkContext` uses Py4J to launch a JVM and create a JavaSparkContext.

Py4J is only used on the driver for local communication between the Python and Java SparkContext objects; large data transfers are performed through a different mechanism.

RDD transformations in Python are mapped to transformations on PythonRDD objects in Java. On remote worker machines, PythonRDD objects launch Python sub-processes and communicate with them using pipes, sending the user's code and the data to be processed.

PS: I'm not sure if this actually answers your question completely.

Comment: It think that the main point here is that PySpark doesn't use multi-threading so GIL is simply not an issue.

Comment: @zero323 can you elaborate your comment?

Comment: There is not much to elaborate. Excluding tests there are only a few places where PySpark is using threads to perform some secondary tasks like starting external process. Everything else it just a good old single threaded processing.

Comment: I concur with @zero323 that's why I said all the parallel processing is dealt with inside the JVM.

Comment: @eliasah To be fair JVM part is not that heavy on multithreading either, don't you think? There are multiple threads required for housekeeping and JVM executors use threads but in practice it is not really required to achieve parallelism in Spark. One could start equivalent number of workers on each machine and get the same parallelism although at a higher price.

Comment: I never said the multithreading is needed to achieve parallelism. I'm not a big fun of that approach neither.

Comment: Spawning up a new thread inside a JVM for each task is much cost-effective and takes less time instead of firing up a new JVM.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ravimalhotra but I'm not sure how it related to my answer...

Comment: @eliasah I was just going through the comment made by zero323 "One could start equivalent number of workers on each machine and get the same parallelism although at a higher price". In response to that just wanted to say that why JVM uses multithreading