# How to run independent transformations in parallel using PySpark?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run 2 functions doing completely independent transformations on a single RDD in parallel using PySpark. What are some methods to do the same?

```
def doXTransforms(sampleRDD):
    (X transforms)

def doYTransforms(sampleRDD):
    (Y Transforms)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="parallelTransforms")
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    hive_context = HiveContext(sc)

    rows_rdd = hive_context.sql("select * from tables.X_table")

    p1 = Process(target=doXTransforms , args=(rows_rdd,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=doYTransforms, args=(rows_rdd,))  
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    sc.stop()
```

This does not work and I now understand this will not work. 
But is there any alternative way to make this work? Specifically are there any python-spark specific solutions?

Comment: If each of your transformations could use (almost) 100% of the cluster resource, which is usually the case, running them in parallel actually makes it slower.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use threads and make sure that cluster have enough resources to process both tasks at the same time.

```py
from threading import Thread
import time

def process(rdd, f):
    def delay(x):
        time.sleep(1)
        return f(x)
    return rdd.map(delay).sum()


rdd = sc.parallelize(range(100), int(sc.defaultParallelism / 2))

t1 = Thread(target=process, args=(rdd, lambda x: x * 2))
t2  = Thread(target=process, args=(rdd, lambda x: x + 1))
t1.start(); t2.start()
```

Arguably this is not that often useful in practice but otherwise should work just fine.

You can further use [in-application scheduling](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) with `FAIR` scheduler and scheduler pools for a better control over execution strategy.

You can also try [`pyspark-asyncactions`](https://github.com/zero323/pyspark-asyncactions) (disclaimer - the author of this answer is also the author of the package) which provides a set of wrappers around Spark API and `concurrent.futures`:

```py
import asyncactions
import concurrent.futures

f1 = rdd.filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0).countAsync()
f2 = rdd.filter(lambda x: x % 11 == 0).countAsync()

[x.result() for x in concurrent.futures.as_completed([f1, f2])]
```

Comment: Threads are not truly parallel in python because of the GIL. So if I use the above method then I will not be able to utilize multiple cores , right?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The only thing that happens in this code is RPC calls. It doesn't touch actual computations. You could handle this in a single thread with async calls as well. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38038346/1560062) and my comments beneath.

Comment: This worked , thanks! Only change I had to make to make it work was to change 
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent from 0.1 to 0.5 in /etc/hadoop/conf/capacity-scheduler.xml.