# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'geq'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to do a multiprocessing in a python script by importing the below module

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Manager,Queue
```

I am trying to run the scripts in the list [1.py,2.py] . During execution one script is successful and other fails both have some dataframe to read .Not sure why it fails .Function used inside the script :
func1 :

```
f=df.where((df[a] >= dat1) & (df[b] <= dat2)) .
```

df : is a dataframe

I want these scripts to be run one by one and not exit out after one script is succesfull . Any Examples or pointers

Comment: Please include the complete error message and the code that produced it

Comment: What you've pasted here (a) has no reference to anything named `geq`, and (b) is a syntax error. Please read [mcve] in the help.

Comment: Meanwhile, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something). Since I'm not sure what you're confused by, I don't know if it answers your question, or it's something you already know.

Comment: @abarnert `geq` is  Java method called on the internal object returned from `DataFrame.__getiitem__`. Probably this code fails because `multiprocessing` is not compatible with Spark - https://stackoverflow.com/q/38048068/8371915