# Applying a udf function in a distributed fashion in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a very basic Spark DataFrame that consists of a couple of columns, one of which contains a value that I want to modify.

```
|| value   || lang ||
| 3        |  en   |
| 4        |  ua   |
```

Say, I want to have a new column per specific class where I would add a float number to the given value (this is not much relevant to the final question though, in reality I do a prediction with sklearn there, but for simplicity let's assume we are adding stuff, the idea is I am modifying the value in some way). So given a dict `classes={'1':2.0, '2':3.0}` I would like to have a column for each class where I add the value from DF to the value of the class and then save it to a csv:

```
class_1.csv
|| value   || lang ||  my_class |  modified  ||
| 3        |  en   |     1      |     5.0    |  # this is 3+2.0
| 4        |  ua   |     1      |     6.0    |  # this is 4+2.0

class_2.csv
|| value   || lang ||  my_class |  modified  ||
| 3        |  en   |     2      |     6.0    |  # this is 3+3.0
| 4        |  ua   |     2      |     7.0    |  # this is 4+3.0
```

So far I have the following code that works and modifies the value for each defined class, but it is done with a for loop and I am looking for a more advanced optimization for it:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

# create session and context
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("SomeApp").getOrCreate()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Some_App').setMaster("local[*]")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)

my_df = spark.read.csv("some_file.csv")

# modify the value here
def do_stuff_to_column(value, separate_class):
    # do stuff to column, let's pretend we just add a specific value per specific class that is read from a dictionary
    class_dict = {'1':2.0, '2':3.0}  # would be loaded from somewhere
    return float(value+class_dict[separate_class])

 # iterate over each given class later
 class_dict = {'1':2.0, '2':3.0}   # in reality have more than 10 classes

 # create a udf function
 udf_modify = udf(do_stuff_to_column, FloatType())

 # loop over each class
 for my_class in class_dict:
    # create the column first with lit
    my_df2 = my_df.withColumn("my_class", lit(my_class))
    # modify using udf function
    my_df2 = my_df2.withColumn("modified", udf_modify("value","my_class"))
    # write to csv now
    my_df2.write.format("csv").save("class_"+my_class+".csv")
```

So the question is, is there a better/faster way of doing this then in a for loop?

Comment: What kind of optimization do you expect? There is nothing specifically wrong with the loop - you have separate sinks, this means separate actions, and each one is properly distributed. You could make [each one asynchronous](https://github.com/zero323/pyspark-asyncactions), or apply some artificial changes (`union` + `partitionBy`) but I doubt you'll get much out of it. You might be able to skip `udf` (it might be a bottleneck), but for that we'll need to see the code.

Comment: @user9613318 I hoped for some way of paralleling the for loop, but couldn't find anything relevant. thanks for the ideas.

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38048068/9613318) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use some form of `join`, in this case `crossJoin`. Here's a MWE:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([(3, 'en'), (4, 'ua')], ['value', 'lang'])
classes = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2.), (2, 3.)], ['class_key', 'class_value'])
res = df.crossJoin(classes).withColumn('modified', F.col('value') + F.col('class_value'))
res.show()
```

For saving as separate CSV's I think there is no better way than to use a loop.

Comment: Thanks, I have to ask, what does MWE stand for?