# Parallelization of large tasks in Python function

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I have a function that I want to multithread/parallelize in Python3.
The `df.myfunc(c1,c2)` function takes a long time to compute, and thus I would like to parallelize it, to speed up the computation for larger datasets.

```
def multi_thread_func(df):
    cols = df.schema.names
    length = len(cols)
    a = np.zeros((length * length))

    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        i = 0
        for value in pool.starmap(df.myfunc, itertools.product(cols, repeat=2)):
            a[i] = None if value is None else value
            i += 1
    return a
```

The specific error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

Comment: What does _"it doesn't seem to work"_ mean?

Comment: @Timus I've fix the specific error message.

Comment: Are you using a Spark dataframe (please tag the df-framework)? If so, you might be on the wrong track. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38048068/14311263) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def multi_thread_func(df):
    length = len(df.cols)
    a = np.zeros((length * length))

    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        i = 0
        for value in pool.starmap(calculate, itertools.product(range(length), repeat=2)):
            a[i] = value
            i += 1

    return a
```

Comment: The above is returning the error: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object.

Comment: Don't know.  It runs just fine for me.  What is it trying to pickle?