# the directory check for /proc/<thread id> return true, although there is no such directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

I'm running this code in bash shell:

```
if [ ! -d /proc/<thread id> ]
then
    echo "There is no such process"
fi
```

It doesn't print error message, although I can see that there is no such directory. When I do the same thing with another id, different from any thread id, it print message.

So for all threads there is also `/proc/<thread id>` directory, which I can't see with ls?

Comment: How are you getting the thread ID? I tried with a couple of threads' PIDs and the directories exist.

Comment: I'm watching in htop, or in task subdirectory of /proc/pid. They shouldn't exist, under /proc should be only processes

Comment: Threads in Linux are processes in all but name. http://stackoverflow.com/a/809049/2072269

Answer (score 2):

I also noticed this problem. After tracing syscalls, it seems that `ls -l /proc/` calls `openat` and then calls `getdents64` syscall. This will only shows PIDs.

However, `stat /proc/TID/` will call `newfstatat`, which can retrieve file information of `/proc/TID`. Guess this issue is caused by kernel implementation of procfs.