# Difference between thread and process from a operating system point of view

Tags: linux

Can you explain to me the difference between a thread and a process from an operating system point of view. I have seen many answers which are explaining this from an application point of view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Threads vs Processes in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807506/threads-vs-processes-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Threads run in shared memory and process in other memory space.

They are both independent sequences of execution but proccess provide resources needed to execute a program like executable code and variables.

Threads contain a process but it contain also a scheduling priority and exception handler.

On linux you can show threads with this comand line : htop -h -p pidofprocess

Comment: Thanks Jean for your time. Can you explain me in detail."Process in other memory space" means?? Can you explain how to check these practically.Is there any command to check threads in process.

Comment: have you tried top -h -p 22362 ? Your error is here because htop is not installed (sudo apt-get htop).